# Building Excel add-ins installer in Visual studio 2010 ( use of MSXML2 for Excel object)

Tags: c#, excel-2010, add-in, msxml3

I wrote an add-ins in Visual studio 2010 and I build an installer to deploy it on Excel 2010. Things used to work fine until I add a reference for Excel object (Interop.MSXML2).

Since then, I am no longer able to deploy it. Excel always crash.  any ideas ? do I need to add the dll into Excel first ?

Thank you in advance!

Brice

Comment: "Interop.MSXML2" is not Excel object, it's Microsoft xml library v2. Also, without the error message or more info, none will help you.

Comment: Initially, it was saying that it is a runtime issue. I did the installation of Visual studio runtime 2010 but it is still crashing after complaining it's still facing difficulties to load the add-ins. I just don't know why ? there is no other specific message, otherwise i would have included it to my question.

By the way i added C:\windows\System32\msxml3.dll and the tool is deployedd on a 64 bit OS.

Comment: Hi; I've just changed the load behaviour from 3 to 2 and the add-ins works fine. thx